# NSInvalidArgumentException : Workout_Tracker.QuickAddViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a class MenuTabs: UIView that corresponds to MenuTabs.xib. I linked them in the identity inspector. In the view is a UICollectionView. I set the UIView as the delegate and datasource for the collection view in storyboard. I'm using the MenuTabs class in a ViewController, but I keep getting this error

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Workout_Tracker.QuickAddViewController collectionView:numberOfItemsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fbbe970a120'
```

Here are my MenuTabs and QuickAddViewController files

```
import UIKit

class MenuTabs: UIView {

let workoutTypes = ["", "", "", ""]

let cellId = "cellId"

@IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    setup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)

    if self.subviews.count == 0 {
        self.setup()
    }
}

func setup() {
    Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MenuTabs", owner: self, options: nil)
    guard let content = contentView else { return }
    contentView.frame = self.bounds
    contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    addSubview(content)
}
}

// MARK: - Delegate and Datasource methods for UICollectionView

extension MenuTabs: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource,
UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return workoutTypes.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

    return cell
}
```

}

```
import UIKit

class QuickAddViewController: UIViewController {

enum MuscleGroup: String {
    case abs = "Abs"
    case arms = "Arms"
    case back = "Back"
    case calves = "Calves"
    case chest = "Chest"
    case legs = "Glutes & Legs"
    case shoulders = "Shoulders"
}

enum WorkoutType: String {
    case bodyWeight = "Body Weight"
    case weightTraining = "Weight Training"
    case sportsAndRecreation = "Sports & Recreation"
    case cardio = "Cardio"
}

@IBOutlet weak var workoutTypesMenu: UIView!


let exercisesData = ExerciseDatabase()

var workoutTypesDictionary = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Array<String>>>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    workoutTypesDictionary = self.exercisesData.exercisesByWorkoutType

    tabBarController?.tabBar.isTranslucent = false

    // Load workoutTypesMenu View
    if let wtMenu = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("MenuTabs", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! MenuTabs? {
        workoutTypesMenu.addSubview(wtMenu)

    }
}

// MARK: - Get data from ExerciseDatabase.swift

// Get the workout types
func getWorkoutTypes() -> [String] {
    var workoutTypesArray : [String] = []
    for workoutType in workoutTypesDictionary.keys {
        workoutTypesArray.append(workoutType)
    }

    return workoutTypesArray
}

// Get the list of muscles or options
func getMusclesOrOptions(for workoutType: String) -> [String] {
    var musclesOrOptionsArray : [String] = []

    let musclesOrOptions = workoutTypesDictionary[workoutType]!.keys

    for muscleOrOption in musclesOrOptions {
        musclesOrOptionsArray.append(muscleOrOption)
    }

    return musclesOrOptionsArray
}

// Get the list of exercises
func getExercisesArray(for workoutType: String, for muscleOrOption: String) -> [String] {
    var exercisesArray : [String] = []

    exercisesArray = workoutTypesDictionary[workoutType]![muscleOrOption]!

    return exercisesArray
}

// Get the selected exercise
func getSelectedExercise(in workoutType: String, for muscleOrOption: String, at index: Int) -> String {
    var selectedExercise : String = ""

    selectedExercise = workoutTypesDictionary[workoutType]![muscleOrOption]![index]

    return selectedExercise
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - WorkoutTypesBar and Muscles and Options Bar
// Set up the WorkoutTypes bar and the muscles and option types bar
```

}

Comment: The error message is clear enough. iOS is using the `QuickAddViewController` as a delegate of the CollectionView. Check all your connections about the delegate and the datasource. Sometimes Interface Builder shows fake connections (when you edited some code or other parts after connected), so you may need to remove all connections and re-connect them.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting up the delegate and datasource through the nib file, I set them in the init method of MenuTabs.swift

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self

    collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)

    setup()
}
```